# What exactly does the selling point "10 times higher geometric detail" of Id Tech 7 mean?

Tags: doom-eternal

Id Tech 7's main selling point has been that it has "10 times the geometric detail" of the predecessor.

Does this actually mean something, or is it marketing garbage?

I don't know about 3d engines, but arbitrarily increasing the number of polygons is something any engine can do; if they refer to speed instead, I'm very skeptical that it can render 10 times as much polygons in the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Some reasonable explanations are:

- Better multithreading for pushing more geometry from CPU to GPU
- New GPU triangle-, light- and occlusion-culling system to not render what isn't on-screen
- Improved LOD system

Source: [gamedev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/706639-any-guess-at-what-exactly-does-the-selling-point-10-times-higher-geometic-detail-of-id-tech-7-mean)